# Which Wordpress plugin should I use to return image files adapted to screen size?

Tags: images, image-processing, wordpress

Some time ago, I listen about a plugin that returns full-size images adapted to display resolution. If the user has a laptop with 1600x1200 pixels, the image returned is the 1600 version, but if the user is browsing with a smartphone with a resolution of 600x1024 it will return the 600 pixel image (or nearest available).

Anybody knows the name of this plugin?

Comment: Every "responsive" them in the free .org repo has this functionality built in.